# Is there a coordinate-free proof of the hamiltonian character of the geodesic flow?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

I do not know if this question is appropriate for this site, but I posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107804/coordinate-free-proof-of-the-hamiltonian-character-of-the-geodesic-flow) without having answers, so now I make this attempt.

Let be $(M,g)$ a pseudoriemannian manifold.  Let us identify the tangent and the cotangent bundles through the musical isomorphism $g^\flat:u\in TM\to g(u,\cdot)\in T^\ast M.$

It is well known that:

> The geodesics of $(M,g),$ i.e. the solutions of
>   $\frac{D}{dt}\gamma=0,$ are integral curves for the hamiltonian vector
>   field of $K:u\in TM\to \tfrac{1}{2}g(u,u)\in\mathbb{R}$ w.r.t. the
>   canonical symplectic form.

**Question** Knowing how to show it using coordinates and Christoffell symbols, I am wondering how to prove it in an intrinsic way.

Comment: Despite the apparent simplicity of the question, I think this is a very good question for this site.

Comment: I have had three interesting answers until now (not being ruled out that there are others in the future), meanwhile I have thought to accept the one giving more details and more supporting references.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may find an elegant proof of this fact on **Paternain's book "Geodesic Flows"** (Birkhauser), in the very first pages. For convenience, I will reproduce the main parts of the argument here:

The most important step is to understand the geometry of $TTM$, the tangent bundle to the tangent bundle of $M$. Henceforth denote $\pi:TM\to M$ the footpoint projection. Note that, along the zero section, there is a canonical identification of $T_{(x,0_x)}TM=T_xM\oplus T_xM$, nevertheless this is not the case for arbitrary points in $TM$. Existence of a canonical horizontal complement to the vertical space $\ker d\pi$ is equivalent to having a connection.

### Connection map:

Fix a connection and consider the *connection map* $K:TTM\to TM$ defined as follows. Consider $\xi\in T_\theta TM$ and a curve $z:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to TM$ s.t. $z(0)=\theta$, $\dot z(0)=\xi$. These give rise to a curve $\alpha=\pi\circ z$ (the projection of $z$ onto $M$)and a vector field $Z$ along $\alpha$, s.t. $z(t)=(\alpha(t),Z(t))$. Then $K$ is defined by $$K_\theta (\xi)=(\nabla_{\dot\alpha} Z)(0).$$

### Horizontal lift:

Now, define the horizontal lift $L_\theta:T_xM\to T_\theta TM$ as follows: given $v\in T_xM$ and $\beta:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to M$ a curve s.t. $\beta(0)=x$ and $\dot\beta(0)=v$, let $W(t)$ be the parallel transport of $v$ along $\beta$ and $\sigma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to TM$ be the curve $\sigma(t)=(\beta(t),W(t))$. Then set $$L_\theta(v)=\dot\sigma(0)\in T_\theta TM.$$

Finally, we recall that in the above language, the geodesic vector field $G:TM\to TTM$ is clearly given by $G(\theta)=L_\theta(v)$.

### Symplectic structure of $TM$:

One can verify that, in the above notation, the canonical symplectic structure of $TM$ can be invariantly written as $$\omega_\theta(\xi,\eta)=g(d_\theta \pi (\xi),K_\theta(\eta))-g(K_\theta(\xi),d_\theta\pi(\eta)).$$

---

> **Prop.** The geodesic field $G$ is the symplectic gradient of the Hamiltonian $H(x,v)=\tfrac12 g_x(v,v)$, i.e., for all $\theta \in TM$ and all $\xi \in T_\theta TM$, $$d_\theta H(\xi)=\omega_\theta (G(\theta),\xi).$$

**Pf.** With a curve $z:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to TM$ s.t. $z(0)=\theta$, $\dot z(0)=\xi$, we have: $$d_\theta H(\xi)=\frac{d}{dt}H(z(t))\big|_{t=0}$$

$$=\tfrac12\frac{d}{dt}g_{\alpha(t)}(Z(t),Z(t))\big|_{t=0}$$

$$=g(K_\theta(\xi),v)$$

$$=g(d_\theta \pi(L_\theta (v)),K_\theta(\xi))$$

$$=g(d_\theta \pi(G(\theta)),K_\theta(\xi))$$

$$=\omega_\theta (G(\theta),\xi)\quad\square$$

Comment: Thank you Renato, I like very much your answer. I need to find out my way through this material, but surely your reference will be helpful 

Answer (score 9):

This is a **very** particular case of something more general: extremals for a non-degenerate Lagrangian correspond to solutions of the corresponding Hamiltonian system. There is no need to use connections at all. Check out Abraham and Marsden.

Comment: Good point. But any chance you could provide a few details for those of us who don't have easy access to Abraham and Marsden?

Comment: @Deane: you might like this (even legal) way to take a look

http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~marsden/books/Foundations_of_Mechanics.html

Comment: With @Stefan, I highly appreciate the Marsden posts his books online, and I hope others do too. But I also think @alvarezpaiva should elaborate the answer, for two reasons: (1) it is good practice to write such elaborations, (2) the few mouse-clicks, the better.

Comment: Viewing things this way, one still needs to demonstrate that the Euler-Lagrange equations are the geodesic equations for the metric. Abraham and Marsden demonstrate this in Theorem 3.7.1 (page 224), but using coordinates, which Giuseppe was trying to avoid. It seems that showing this invariantly would still require the introduction of a connection, no? (Presumably the connection mentioned by A&M in the remarks on the bottom of page 227 is the same one introduced by the two posters above - though I would need to check to be sure.)

Comment: BTW apologies for the bump - accidentally posted an answer instead of a comment - doh!

Comment: @Paul Skerrit: Thanks for the comment and now I think I misread the problem.  It seems to me that Giuseppe's question has two parts to it, each with a well-known answer: (1) a coordinate-free proof of the first variation formula in a pseudo-Riemannian manifold can be
found in lots of places. For example in Jost's book "Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis"; (2) A coordinate-free proof that the Euler-Lagrange equations of a regular Lagrangian are Hamiltonian
(using Cartans formula for Lie derivatives) is also quite classical, but I'll look for a good reference. 




Comment: Dear Alvarezpaiva, thanks a lot for your answer. Excuse me if my question was prone to be misunderstood, because I should have claimed as starting point my understanding of geodesic flow. Taking the coordinate expression of the equation for geodesic curve (as Def.1.4.2 in Jost) I recognize them as the projection on the base of the geodesic spray: \emph{the unique vector field on $TM$ which is horizontal and special} (i.e. second order edo on $M$) 

Answer (score 6):

Here is an outline of a proof. It relies on the splitting of the tangent bundle of the tangent bundle $$TTM=VTM\oplus HTM$$
into the vertical part $VTM=ker d\pi,$ where $\pi\colon TM\to M,$ and into the Horizontal part, which is induced by the Levi-Civita connection as follows: Let $v\in T_pM$ and $\gamma$ be a curve centered at $p.$ Take the parallel section $v$ along $\gamma$ through $v$ wrt Levi Civita: Then, by definition,
$v'(0)\in H_vTM\subset TvTM,$ and this construction gives a well-defined bundle complement of the vertical space in $TTM.$ Note that both $VTM$ and $HTM$ are canonically isomorphic to $\pi^*TM.$
This enables one to define a almost complex structure $J$ on TTM by switching in the appropriate way from $HTM$ to $VTM$ and vice versa. (I don't want to give a formula, as this would cause sign problems..). Moreover one gets an induced metric from M, which makes $HTM$ orthogonal to $VTM,$  denoted by $G.$

The first thing is to show that  (lets call the symplectic form $\omega$)
$$\omega(A,B)=\pm G(A,JB)$$ 
for all $A,B\in T_vTM.$ This again uses the definition of $HTM$ as well as Cartan formula. This can be done without coordinates.

The derivative of $K$ along the vertical space is just given as
$$d_vK=G(\hat v,.),$$
where $\hat v\in V_vTM\subset T_vTM$ is the vertical vector corresponding to $\in T_pM.$
Therefore, the hamiltonian vector field $\xi$ of $K$ is given by $\pm J\hat v$ which is (after taking care with the sign) exactly the horizontal lift of $v\in T_pM$ to $H_vTM.$ An integral curve $\hat\gamma$ of $\xi$
is automatically a parallel section of $TM$ along its projection $\gamma=\pi\circ \hat\gamma,$ and as
$\gamma'(t)=\hat\gamma(t),$ $\gamma$ must be a geodesic.

Comment: Dear Sebastian, thank you. Would you suggest me some readings following the same line of your exposition?

Comment: Dear Giuseppe, I am sorry that I don't know any good reference for this, but the part concerning horizontal bundles is contained in a book of Michor,.., you can find it here: http://www.emis.de/monographs/KSM/kmsbookh.pdf

Comment: This follows simply from the fact that levi civita connection is defined in such a way that the energy integrals over geodesics be stationary. Hamiltionian vector fields are time flows of sympletic manifolds given by the principle of extreme action. If your action consists only of the hamiltonian in question, extremizing it will give geodesics as integral curves of the hamiltonian vector field.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that $G$ and $G'$ be the vector fields on $\mathrm{T}M$ that describe the first and the second definition of the geodesic flow; we need to show that $G=G'$.

If the metric tensor $g$ is flat, then $G=G'$ (it should be obvious).

Now assume that two metric tenors $g_0$ and $g_1$ on $M$ coincide at a point $p$ up to first order.
Observe that $G_0=G_1$ and $G'_0=G'_1$ on $\mathrm{T}_p$.

Finally, observe that given a Riemannian metric $g_1$ there is a flat metric $g_0$  that coincides with $g_1$ up to first at a given point $p$.

Answer (score 0):

This follows simply from the fact that levi civita connection is defined in such a way that the energy integrals over geodesics be stationary. Hamiltionian vector fields are  time flows of sympletic manifolds given by the principle of extreme action. If your action consists only of the hamiltonian in question, extremizing it will give geodesics as integral curves of the hamiltonian vector field.